# Wordpress Plugin Setting's POST

Tags: plugin-development, query-posts, options

I've developed a few plugin for Wordpress. Currently I've not been able to replicate the way wp save settings. I've a setting page which I learned from a tutorial. It POST to `option.php`, and wp take care of saving the data.

But I have some custom option page which require more complex handling. Basically I wanted to POST some data to my own php, then redirect back to the original page/url after handling. I can't find a "proper" way to redirect correctly, i.e. without load the whole page then redirect using javascript.

Currently I use GET with `add_query_arg()`, the url will display the data that I passed. Using POST will trigger a redirect prompt when refreshed.

Is there a built in wp function that does it automatically? OR If I were to POST to `option.php`, how should I access the data without it handling automatically?

EDIT: Example of one of the complex page would be like this:

I assign a usermeta to some users which we would call SU (SpecialUser). To ease the job of admin, I have a page to display the list of users with a column showing whether they are SU. The text in that column of each row is a link which if clicked, will toggle the state of SU for that user. Currently I use GET, to pass the id of the user and also action to be carried out. Then page itself will detect, if both action and id is valid, the state of the user is toggled. At the same time, the updated result is displayed. The GET query remain at the URL

What I would really like to do is to use POST, pass the id and action to the same page, then toggle the state but not displaying anything, then "redirect" back to the page displaying the updated user list. What I've tried earlier while implementing this is to use javascript to redirect the page, but this means it will have to load the whole page before the javascript can be executed. It's not resource friendly. I would like it to work much like how the Settings API would.

Sorry for the long explaination. I'm sure there's a term to what I wanted to do, but I'm not sure what it is.

Thanks

EDIT: It's more or less like the Plugin page, when you activate/deactivate the plugin. The plugin page is using GET. The problem I have is actually redirecting, so GET or POST shouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a way to overcome what I needed by using [wp_redirect()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_redirect). I'm calling `wp_redirect()` after I've done processing. Also following advise from [WordPress and wp_redirect() function problem](http://www.lessthanweb.com/blog/wordpress-and-wp_redirect-function-problem), I added `noheader=true` to the form's action or link to prevent the error "header already sent" from php.

Answer (score 3):

if you are using the [**Settings API**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API) then you can use your own php inside the $sanitize_callback of your [**register_setting**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_setting) and return the value you want to save after doing your "more complex handling".

Comment: The WordPress Settings API is incredibly powerful and flexible, and is definitely the way to go here.

Comment: Thanks, yes, you're right. I'm using Settings API for the "simple" setting page. As for the complex one, I'm creating something similar to the "Posts" (`wp-admin/edit.php`) but without ajax. Do you know any similar tutorial I can pickup from? The Settings API is already complicated enough for me.

Comment: I think I can't use Settings API for the complex page, since the users who are going to use them doesn't have "manage_options" capability but it's required according to http://codex.wordpress.org/Settings_API

Comment: can you explain the use case? what are you trying to do?

Comment: Hi Bainternet, I've updated my question. Please take a look. Tq

Comment: Do you mean an AJAX post?

Comment: No, I intend to use form POST

Comment: It's more or less like the Plugin page, when you activate/deactivate the plugin